# Get data from DB facade en php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I have this query en php laravel

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT * FROM solicitudes WHERE id = 5");
```

My table "solicitudes" have the columns "id, titulo, proveedor"

The query result is only one row, and I want to take the value of "titulo".
I try it with something like this...

```
$nombrep = 'nombre'.$query->titulo;
```

but this throws an error

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: `DB::select` returns an array so use `$query['titulo']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `DB::select` returns array. And If you want use -> . Try this:

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT * FROM solicitudes WHERE id = 5");
$query = Illuminate\Support\Collection::make($query);

$nombrep = 'nombre'.$query[0]->titulo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have an [`Eloquent  Model`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) for `solicitudes` table :

```
$result = Solicitude::findOrFail(5);
```

This will return a single instance representing single row having `id`(primary key) is `5`. If will throw error is there is no row present with `id` as `5`;

When you use :

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT * FROM solicitudes WHERE id = 5");
```

It gives an array. And secondly even if you are anticipating this query should return a single array or object, it does not.

It returns an array which contains the single object representing  the row.

If you have models defined, then using ELoquent query builders is the cleaner thing to do.